# How to get mod_proxy_fcgi on CentOS/Red Hat 6 with Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, centos6, mod-proxy-fcgi

I am trying to get Apache 2.2 + php-fpm to work on CentOS 6.5 (and Red Hat later). I want to use mod_proxy_fcgi to do this, but I can't find a proper way to get it.

I tried looking for repository including it, but I only found it packaged with Apache 2.4.

Is there an easy way to install and maintain it ? Is the only solution to compile it ?

Also, if I have no other choice, what's the best way to get Apache 2.4 for CentOS 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_proxy_fcgi` needs Apache 2.3 and later, which is why you get it packaged with Apache 2.4 and not with 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

For the Ceph project we needed to backport mod_proxy_fcgi to httpd 2.2 on RHEL 6, and I've put this package in EPEL. Enable EPEL, then "yum install mod_proxy_fcgi"

Answer (score 0):

httpd-2.4 rpms for CentOS 6 can be found at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/SCL/ .
These are from the Software Collections that are built to run alongside the base packages.
Unfortunately, this collection is only for X86_64. The repos in /etc/yum.repos.d do not contain a definition to reach this collection so you will have to create one. Into a file named /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SCL.repo copy the following:

```
  [SCL]
    name=CentOS-6 - SCL software collections alongside
    #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=SCL&infra=$infra
    baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/SCL/$basearch/
    gpgcheck=1
    enabled=1
    gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

I had to comment out the mirrorlist and edit the baseurl because processing of mirrorlist resulted in converting SCL to scl which didn't match any directory on the server.
Now you can install the apache 2.4 server as easily as:

```
  yum install httpd24-httpd
```

which installs:

```
  httpd24-httpd, httpd24-apr, httpd24-apr-util, httpd24-httpd-tools, httpd24-runtime
```

The mod_proxy_fcgi module is installed as part of the httpd24-httpd package.

The SCL has mariadb55, mysql55, nodejs010, perl516, php54, postgresql92, python27, python33, ruby193 and others. Enjoy!

The SRPMS are available at http://vault.centos.org/6.5/SCL/Source/SPackages/ for 6.5 and likewise for 6.6.