# Issue with configuring php-fpm mod proxy on centos 6

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, centos6, php5, mod-proxy

I'm configuring PHP_FPM on a Centos 6 distribution. I'm using php 5.4.45 and apache 2.2.15 and the "mod_proxy.so" to call the socket. But with the following Vhost and php-fpm configuration I still get the same two issues in my site logs :

```
[Tue Mar 10 11:36:49 2020] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:0 (*) failed
[Tue Mar 10 11:36:49 2020] [error] [client 192.168.1.38] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

I'have tried and read a huge amount of solutions but no one of them helped me so much.
Here the configuration of my Vhost and php-fpm www.conf file :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

   <Directory "/var/www/html">
           Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog logs/default-error_log
   LogLevel warn
   TransferLog logs/default-access_log
   CustomLog logs/default-request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/$1
    DirectoryIndex index.php info.php

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
```

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/default.sock
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660
user = apache
group = apache
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
php_value[opcache.file_cache] = /var/lib/php/opcache
```

Thank you for you attention.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache 2.2 natively does not have `mod_proxy_fcgi` (cf. [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/616840/530633)), you must have obtained it from [alternative sources](https://github.com/ceph/mod-proxy-fcgi). Moreover using `mod_proxy` with the `SetHandler` directive works [from version 2.4.10](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#handler). Therefore:

1. Your `<FilesMatch>` block has no effect, so you can delete it,
2. Only your `ProxyPassMatch` directive is working. However your version of `mod_proxy_fcgi` does not support Unix Domain Sockets, so you need to connect to **PHP-FPM** using a `TCP/IP` socket. In order to do so, modify the `www.conf` file and replace the `listen` directive with:

   ```
   listen 127.0.0.1:9000
   ```

   and restart **PHP-FPM**. On Apache 2 side replace the `ProxyPassMatch` directive with:

   ```
   ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
   ```

   and reload **Apache2**.